# How to show a morphism is etale?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was read [this paper](http://www.numdam.org/article/BSMF_1974__102__335_0.pdf).
Proposition 2.6: there is a morphism between schemes (actually between closed sets in projective spaces over $\mathbb{C}$) $f:X\to Y$. We want to show it is etale at some point $x$. We also know the fiber at $y:=f(x)$ contains only $x$. Then the author construct the following Cartesian diagram which I do not think make sense:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Z @>>> X\\
@V{f'}VV @VV{f}V \\
\mathrm{Spec}(\mathscr{O}_{Y,y}) @>>> Y
\end{CD}$$
And he claims: $a'$ is finite morphism, assume $Z=\mathrm{Spec}(B)$ (locally?), $B$ is $\mathscr{O}_{Y,y}$-algebra that is finite and local. By Nakayama, we will get $B\cong\mathscr{O}_{Y,y}$?

First $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathscr{O}_{Y,y})$ looks weird to me. I have never used this construction.

Second, what is $Z:=\mathrm{Spec}(\mathscr{O}_{Y,y})\times_Y X$, does it have anything to do with $\mathscr{O}_{X,x}$? If we want to show the etaleness of $f$, we need to show some properties of the stalk at $x$ but it never appears. I don't see why this is enough to say $f$ is etale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the morphism is between projective varieties is actually important to this proof. As projective varieties, $X$ is proper and $Y$ is separated, so the map $f:X\to Y$ is proper. By upper semicontinuity of fiber dimension, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $y$ so that $f^{-1}(U)\to U$ is quasifinite, and as quasifinite + proper = finite, we have that $f^{-1}(U)\to U$ is actually a finite morphism. We rewrite our diagram to update our situation:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Z @>>> f^{-1}(U) @>>> X\\
@V{a'}VV @V{a|_U}VV @VV{a}V \\
Spec(\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}) @>>> U @>>> Y
\end{CD}$$

where $a|_U$ is finite. Then $a'$ is the base change of a finite morphism and thus is also finite - in particular, it's affine, so $Z$ is affine as well, so writing $Z=\operatorname{Spec} B$ makes sense. If one can show that $B$ is flat over $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$ then it must be free and then via Nakayma isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$ as there's an isomorphism after modding out by $\mathfrak{m}$ (as the fiber consists of one point). ($B$ is not a priori the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$, but it is after a finite localization, which is etale.)

Unfortunately, there is a gap here according to what you've presented. Consider $X=\operatorname{Spec} k[x]/(x^2)$ and $Y=\operatorname{Spec} k$ with the natural map between them, which fulfills the assumptions you've mentioned in your post. Then $k[x]/(x^2)$ is a finite local $k$-algebra but it's not flat. You should search the paper for missing assumptions you have not included in your post (for instance, if $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay at $x$ and $Y$ is smooth at $y$, then this would suffice by miracle flatness).

Comment: Thanks! Why do we take the fiber product over $Spec(O_{Y,y})$? Why this implies the map is etale at that point?
We actually want to get $Y$ is smooth at $y$ so probably we can not assume that. But we know $X$ is smooth at $x$ and $Y$ is just the image of $X$, probably we can also assume reduced irreducible, also $k=\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Many [characterizations](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02GU) of etale morphisms rely on proving facts about $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$, so it's natural to choose a proof strategy which involves it. Using fiber products is also pretty reasonable - they're well understood and have lots of nice properties. Modulo the missing argument about flatness, this proof is rather quick and not too hard to understand - I might choose it when writing, for instance.

Comment: Secondly, knowing $X$ smooth at $x$ doesn't fix this. Consider the resolution of singularities $\Bbb P^1\to V(y^2z-x^3)\subset \Bbb P^2$. $X$ is smooth, $Y$ is integral, the map is finite, and yet still at the singular point the map is not etale (as if it were, then $Y$ would be smooth, which it isn't). You need more - are you sure that you've correctly identified all the assumptions of the author?

Comment: So in this case, after the fiber product $B$ is the stalk at $x$? 
What he wanted was: Let $X$ be a closed set in $\mathbb{P}^N\times(\mathbb{P}^2)^n$ representing the space of curves with $n$ nodes the first $\mathbb{P}^N$ is the parametrization of curve coefficient, the last patch is the nodes so a point looks like $(C,p_1,...,p_n)$. We write some equations: points passing the curve, points have vanishing Jacobian at these points.

Comment: These equations define a subspace which is the $X_0$. Now, we want just the curve so we project it onto $\mathbb{P}^N$. But we can see that we can swap the order of points, so we mod an action $S_n$. Say $X:=X_0/S_n$. Now, the image is still $Y$. We want to prove that the map is etale at the points representing curves with distinct nodes. Of course, we can not hope it is etale at every point since the boundary can be very crazy. The $X$ is the one after quotient by the group action. $X_0\to X$ is etale? We have to show $X\to Y$ is etale at these points.

Comment: As you mentioned these characterstics of etaleness, but seems $\mathscr{O}_{X,x}$  never appeared in the proof. I just got stuck how to proof $f$ is flat (other conditions are satisfied): maybe I guess the author wanted the $B$ is $\mathscr{O}_{X,x}$ or related? And he proved they are isomorphic via the induced stalk map?

Comment: Ah, I see what you're getting at with the complaint about $B$. In general, $B\cong \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is false - try something like $\Bbb P^1\times \Bbb P^1\to \Bbb P^1$, for instance. On the other hand, the map from $B$ to the local ring is etale as it's flat + locally of finite presentation + the fiber over the closed point is just a copy of $\Bbb C$. If one can prove that $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}\to B$ is etale, then as the composition of etale maps is etale, we get $f$ is etale at $x$. It sounds like explaining the author's intent needs more than comments - can you put the setup in the question?

Comment: I changed it, but now I got what you and the author's intension, almost. You mean the map $B\to\mathscr{O}_{X,x}$ is obtained by filling the Cartesian square? I can see that it has the other properties. But again why this map is flat?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "filling in the square" - the square is already cartesian. It might help you to see an example to understand how $B$ and $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ are different: let $X=\Bbb A^2$, $Y=\Bbb A^1$, $x=0$, $y=0$, and $f$ the obvious projection map.  Then $B$ is $k[x,y]$ localized at the set of polynomials in $x$ with nonzero constant term, while $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}$. In particular, $y+1$ is invertible in the latter but not the former. I'll look at the edit tomorrow when I have more time.

Comment: Sorry, I did not expresse myself very clearly: not really filling the square, but use the universal property: there is a map from $B\to\mathscr O_{X,x}$. I was troubled by this map: why did you get the information that it is flat (the other two were clear I guess). I also dont not think the $B$ and the local ring are the same thing, either.

Comment: Localization is flat. This is standard and can be found in most references.