# Nakayama's lemma implies isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

It was originally related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3434306/how-to-show-a-morphism-is-etale). I think it worthy to ask separately.

Known is: $X=\mathrm{Spec}(S),\ Y=\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ are affine, $f$ is finite morphism, actually the fiber has only **one** point at $y$ which is $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C)$. If needed we can also think they are just closed subsets of $\mathbb {A}^n,\mathbb {A}^m$. Now consider the fiber product:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Z @>>> X\\
@V{f'}VV @VV{f}V \\
\mathrm{Spec}(\mathscr{O}_{Y,y}) @>>> Y
\end{CD}$$
We want to conclude that $Z\to \mathrm{Spec}(\mathscr{O}_{Y,y})$ isomorphism.

We can translate into commutative algebra by reversing the arrows:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
R @>>> R_{\mathfrak{p}}\\
@V{g}VV @VV{g'}V \\
S @>>> S\otimes_{R}R_{\mathfrak{p}}
\end{CD}$$

We know that the $g,g'$ arrows are finite. $B:=S\otimes_{R}R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a finite $R$-algebra.

The [author](http://www.numdam.org/article/BSMF_1974__102__335_0.pdf) in proposition 2.6 just claimed that $B$ is also local and then by Nakayama, they are isomorphism? I do not understand these arguments.

Answer (score 3):

You may assume from the outset that $Y=\text{Spec}(R)$ for $(R,{\mathfrak m})$ local and that $X=\text{Spec}(S)$ with $(S,{\mathfrak n})$ local and finitely generated over $R$. The assumption on the fibre translates as $S/{\mathfrak m}\cong{\mathbb C}$, and you intend to conclude that $R\to S$ is an isomorphism.

In this generality, however, this isn't true: Pick for example $R={\mathbb R}\to {\mathbb C}=S$.

In your original question, though, you seem to be working over $\text{Spec}({\mathbb C})$, so let's assume $R,S$ are $k$-algebras for some field $k$ and $k\stackrel{\cong}{\to} S/{\mathfrak n}$. Since $k\to S/{\mathfrak n}$ factors as $k\to R/{\mathfrak m}\to S/{\mathfrak m}S\to S/{\mathfrak n}$, we get that $R/{\mathfrak m}\cong S/{\mathfrak m} S\cong k$. We still want to prove that $R\to S$ is an isomorphism.

However, it's still not true. Pick for example $R = k[x]/(x^2)\twoheadrightarrow k=S$.

The missing property here was already mentioned in [How to show a morphism is etale?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3434306/how-to-show-a-morphism-is-etale): Flatness. So, let's assume in addition that $S$ is a flat $R$ module. Then we're in the game: A finitely generated, flat module over a Noetherian ring is projective, and finitely generated projective modules over local Noetherian rings are free. Then, ignoring ring structures, $R\to S$ is a morphism between finitely generated free $R$-modules which becomes an isomorphism under $-\otimes_R R/{\mathfrak m}$. Nakayama then implies that $R\to S$ is an isomorphism of $R$-modules, hence of rings.

If you want to avoid the general above statements about flat, projective and free modules, here's a more direct argument, this time starting with Nakayama: The morphism of finitely-generated $R$-modules $R\to S$ is an isomorphism (in particular surjective) after applying $-\otimes_R R/{\mathfrak m}$, so Nakayama implies that already $R\to S$ is surjective. Hence $S=R/I$ for some ideal $I\lhd R$. It's therefore sufficient to show that $R\to R/I$ is flat if and only if $I=0$: For this, consider the exact sequence of $R$-modules $0\to I\to R\to R/I\to 0$. Applying $-\otimes_R R/I$ gives $I/I^2\to R/I\stackrel{\cong}{\to} R/I\to 0$, so if $R/I$ is flat over $R$, we get $I/I^2 = 0$, hence $I = I^2$, and a forteriori $I = {\mathfrak m}I$. Viewing $I$ as a finitely generated $R$-module, Nakayama implies $I=0$ as desired.

Comment: It seems to me like Nakayama's lemma rarely shows up without some mention of smoothness, flatness, or anything with $I^2$ involved

Comment: @ZxJx I wouldn't agree to that - the Nakayama Lemma is so general (and simple) that it's use goes beyond context solely dealing withh smooth and/or flat morphisms.

Comment: You are correct, I had forgotten all the times Nakayama showed up!  My apologies

Comment: @Upc Do you have any questions?

Comment: Would it be safe for me to tell myself "Nakayama's Lemma is useful for when you want to say something that works for vector spaces but you want to say it about a certain module" ?